# Spring repository filter with specification Blob column, which string array in java

Tags: java, arrays, spring-data-jpa, predicate

i have BLOB column in Mysql database.

In java this column parsed as string array:

```
    @Column(
    name = "categories",
    nullable = false,
    length = 2048
)
private String[] categories;
```

This class have spring repository method findAll which uses predicates from Specification for filtering:

```
    Page<Campaign> findAll(Specification<Campaign> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

For colum with type String we create predicate with next code example:

```
    public static <T extends AbstractPersistable> Predicate likeLower(Root<T> root, CriteriaBuilder cb, String name, String value) {
    if (isBlank(value)) {
        return null;
    }
    return cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(name)), '%' + value + '%');
}
```

im create predicate with code below :
        `predicates.add(likeLower(root, cb, "categories", filterCategories));`

When i run query `SELECT * FROM persona_adserver.campaign where categories like '%asino%';` in mysql directly i receive 209 rows as result.

But when i pass predicate to repositoy i have exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [%asino%] did not match expected type [[Ljava.lang.String; (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%asino%] did not match expected type [[Ljava.lang.String; (n/a)]
```

Update 1

filterCategories comes from api request as String param

Comment: does it work if you get rid of cb.lower?

Comment: Try replacing "cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(name)), '%' + value + '%');" with cb.like(root.get(name), '%' + value + '%');. See what happens

Comment: And show where filterCategories comes from

Comment: @jgleoj23 changin to cb.like(root.get(name), '%' + value + '%'); didn change situation.  still have same error